# How to parse json string created by stringify function in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I want to parse the json string in java class (.java) created by stringify() function in javascript. I know to parse the string like:

```
                String JSON_DATA
                = "{"
                + "  \"geodata\": ["
                + "    {"
                + "      \"id\": \"1\","
                + "      \"name\": \"Julie Sherman\","
                + "      \"gender\" : \"female\","
                + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.33774833333334\","
                + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.88670166666667\""
                + "    },"
                + "    {"
                + "      \"id\": \"2\","
                + "      \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\","
                + "      \"gender\" : \"male\","
                + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.336453\","
                + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.884985\""
                + "    }"
                + "  ]"
                + "}";
```

but how to parse this string?

```
        var IO = {
        //returns array with storable google.maps.Overlay-definitions
        IN: function(arr, //array with google.maps.Overlays
                encoded//boolean indicating whether pathes should be stored encoded
                ) {
            var shapes = [],
                    goo = google.maps,
                    shape, tmp;

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                shape = arr[i];
                tmp = {type: this.t_(shape.type), id: shape.id || null};


                switch (tmp.type) {
                    case 'CIRCLE':
                        tmp.radius = shape.getRadius();
                        tmp.geometry = this.p_(shape.getCenter());
                        break;
                    case 'MARKER':
                        tmp.geometry = this.p_(shape.getPosition());
                        break;
                    case 'RECTANGLE':
                        tmp.geometry = this.b_(shape.getBounds());
                        break;
                    case 'POLYLINE':
                        tmp.geometry = this.l_(shape.getPath(), encoded);
                        break;
                    case 'POLYGON':
                        tmp.geometry = this.m_(shape.getPaths(), encoded);

                        break;
                }
                shapes.push(tmp);
            }

            return shapes;
        }
```

and the string formed to be parsed is:

```
[{"type":"CIRCLE","id":null,"radius":1730.4622192451884,"geometry":[32.3610810916614,50.91339111328125]},{"type":"CIRCLE","id":null,"radius":1831.5495077322266,"geometry":[32.35528086804335,50.997161865234375]},{"type":"CIRCLE","id":null,"radius":1612.2461023303567,"geometry":[32.34454947365649,51.011924743652344]}]
```

Comment: do you want to parse a json string in javascript? you question is no clear

Comment: You may use Gson for parsing Json in Java: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: yes i want to parse the string in java class .java not in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for this. Create a POJO that hold the data and use these libs. An eg with Gson

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

class JsonData {
    private String type;
    private String id;
    private double radius;
    private List<Double> geometry;

    //Getters & Setters
}

public class JsonParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "[{\"type\":\"CIRCLE\",\"id\":null,\"radius\":1730.4622192451884,\"geometry\":[32.3610810916614,50.91339111328125]},{\"type\":\"CIRCLE\",\"id\":null,\"radius\":1831.5495077322266,\"geometry\":[32.35528086804335,50.997161865234375]},{\"type\":\"CIRCLE\",\"id\":null,\"radius\":1612.2461023303567,\"geometry\":[32.34454947365649,51.011924743652344]}]";

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<JsonData>>() {}.getType();
        List<JsonData> disputeSummaryArraylistobjectList = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
        System.out.println(disputeSummaryArraylistobjectList);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a JSON parser for Java like [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

There are two strategies for parsing:

1. Creating Java objects and let the JSON parsers map elements in the input to fields
2. Iterating over the generic JSON data structure which the parser returns

The documentation of both projects contain lots of examples how to achieve either.